# Cannot burn .iso onto either a USB nor a rewriteable DVD

Tags: ubuntu, dvd, burning, iso-image

Using a Dell e6500 Latitude Laptop running Ubuntu (Maverick).  I've been trying desperately using wodim, growisofs, dd, and cdrecord to try and write a Windows .iso to some sort of media (Yes, it is legal. It's Enterprise version and is being provided through my college).  For some reason I do not know, I've been getting error after error regarding being either incapable of writing to the medium or else being incapable of sensing and running the software at boottime.

Eventually I was capable of pressing through the process of writing to both the DVD drive and the USB drive (whether or not it was properly or not I don't know. I never found out how to verify the data after the burning process). During boottime, when booting from the USB, it eventually says that there is no boot sector on the flash drive. When done with the DVD, it simply never gives an output and just fails, defaulting into booting Ubuntu.

At this point I'm at wits end. I've sifted through so many forum posts and have been trying desperately to understand why my system is acting like this. If you think you might be able to help, *please do*. I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Can you compare MD5 hash to the original to verify it's not a corrupt ISO? Also, have you verified the ISO is supposed to boot?

Comment: Cannot compare MD5. The college didn't provide the MD5 for the file. Is it possible to compare the .iso's data with the data written after burning? As for whether or not it's supposed to be booted from... I hope so. :( Now I need to double check.

Edit: Running another burn. Will see if I can initiate setup from within Ubuntu.

Comment: @emgee

Unsure unfortunately. It gives the impression that it can be run from a Windows OS. There was a readme file that came with the iso:

"This disc contains a "UDF" file system and requires an operating system
that supports the ISO-13346 "UDF" file system specification."

In any case, I'm unsure if it can be booted from or run from Ubuntu.

Comment: Think I may have found the answer to my own question. Will update again in a bit...

http://www.redmezzanine.com/?p=420&lang=en

Comment: Yeah. Problem fixed. Guess I didn't RTFM carefully enough. There is a huuuuuge difference between ISO 9660 and ISO 13346 and that's what caused the problem. Thanks for the help emgee.

Comment: @Rasnag: If you fixed it, post the fix as your own answer.